# (onClick attribute) it is not in the attribute box in Android Studio

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, onclick, attributes

How can this problem be solved? Also, there are many attributes for example (textColor, font, background, backgroundColor) that are not in the attribute box in Android Studio (https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDKS8.png)

Should be (onClick attribute) it in the Attributes box in Android Studio